# Best way to call multiple fetch calls for multiple pages? (also await/then)

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I'm trying to get all of the characters from this Star Wars API and I'm fairly new to JS. I'm wondering what the best way of doing it is. I came up with a couple of solutions. The second solution looks clean; however, it's kind of hard coded since it leaves out the possibility that more pages could get added.

Thanks for your time.

```
const characters = [];
var url;

async function getAllRequests(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    url = data.next;
    characters.push(...data.results);
    if(url !== null) {
        return getAllRequests(url);
    }
}

function foo(index) {
    let url = 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=1';
    getAllRequests(url);
}
```

```
function getAllRequests(url) {
    for(let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        requests.push(fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=' + i));
    }
    return requests;   
}
async function foo(index) {
    const responses = await Promise.all(getAllRequests());
    const data = await Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json()));
    data.forEach(object => characters.push(...object.results));
}
```

Also, I'm trying to understand the difference between using promises with the .then syntax and using await.

```
function foo(index) {
    Promise.all(getAllRequests())
    .then(response => Promise.all(response.map(res => res.json())))
    .then(data => data.forEach(object => characters.push(...object.results)));

    console.log(characters)
}
```

```
async function foo(index) {
    const responses = await Promise.all(getAllRequests());
    const data = await Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json()));
    data.forEach(object => characters.push(...object.results));

    console.log(characters)
}
```

In the .then example, it takes a couple seconds to load the data as taken from my gifs: first gif is me reloading and checking the output instantly, second is me checking output after a couple seconds

https://gyazo.com/26347087a68e0058972516b45a65a35e

https://gyazo.com/68985bcf20926618c0e6b9731fb22c53

In the await example, it seems as if it literally waits for the promise to finish before carrying on with the remaining code:
https://gyazo.com/6171b20375f14121b409a8944bd07932

So, is the difference that await pauses execution and the .then syntax doesn't?

Comment: async/await is equivalent to pre version promise. it's just a new syntax in es7.

Comment: The second way is more readable and easy to understand. there's no difference in performance side at all.

Comment: "*The second solution looks clean; however, it's kind of hard coded since it leaves out the possibility that more pages could get added.*" - yes, exactly that is the problem. If you want to properly use the pagination that is offered by swapi, then you need to use the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example will certainly be more efficient than your first, because the first is serialising the HTTP requests, whereas the second allows them to occur in parallel.

However, if there is a possibility that other pages could be added, and this is only determined via responses, then your first example may be necessary.

---

With regard to your `await` / `then` examples, your `await` version is equivalent to this:

```
function foo(index) {
    Promise.all(getAllRequests())
    .then(response => Promise.all(response.map(res => res.json())))
    .then(data => {
        data.forEach(object => characters.push(...object.results));
        console.log(characters);
    });
}
```

Without nesting `console.log` inside your final `then()`, it will be executed immediately after your `Promise` is created, not after it completes.